# Will doing a master's thesis in an unrelated field hurt my job prospects?

Tags: thesis, masters, job-search, germany, electrical-engineering

I am having trouble with this study situation. Recently I was offered a master thesis topic at work where I work a part time student job.  My role is Java Developer and master thesis topic is related to software development.  However, the master study I am currently enrolled is in Electronics Engineering.  My bachelor was also in Electronics.  But my all previous full time work experiences are in the software industry.

Now I am wondering if it is a bad thing on my resume if my master thesis topic is not directly related to Electronics. Am I hurting my profile here if my goal is to find a full time job quickly?

Comment: Do you have an advisor that you can discuss this with? And it depends on your goals: your "profile" for what, exactly?

Comment: Profile for getting a full-time job after I finish my master's study. I study in Germany. My advisor from the university said if I am interested in this topic then I can choose it as a master thesis. He said it is not directly related to Electronics but it still works as a master thesis.

Comment: Then it probably depends more on the job market than anything else. Especially if you intend to stay where you are.

Comment: Yes my plan is to get blue card here for long term stay :)

Comment: Would this question be better suited to the Workplace Stack?

Comment: Oh do I need to move it there? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to work in the software industry, then a thesis on that subject would be more helpful than one on electronics. And vice versa: if your long term goal is to work in electronics, then a software-oriented thesis isn't as helpful.

That doesn't mean it's not helpful at all. Anyone completing a master's degree is showing that they're smart and persistent. A lot of people end up in a career that's not 100% aligned with what they studied - for example, a lot of people with physics and astronomy degrees are finding employment as data scientists, a job field that barely existed ten years ago.

Don't feel too compelled to choose right now what you'll be interested in for the rest of your whole life. There are plenty of opportunities to shift course. Doing any decent master's thesis will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your advisor is happy and the local job market is aligned, then do which ever you want. For longer term goals it might be different. But your employability is probably determined by what you have done recently.